# Flutter & Dart : how to retrive map field data from firestore?

Tags: flutter, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

[image]

Maps key is dynamic key, so i cant set a class to use fromjson method,

```
Map<String, double> rating;
```

i set the data , it working;

```
data['rating'] = json.encode(this.rating);
```

i try to get data, not working;

```
rating = jsonDecode(json['rating']);
```

igot the error:

```
Expected a value of type 'Map<String, double>', but got one of type 'String'
```

how can i get the data as Map ?

Comment: Because as it is clearly visible that the stored data is String and not map

Comment: I'm not familiar with firestore, but the screenshot shows that it is in fact a string and not a map, because it has quotes around it

Answer (score 1):

json.encode turns it into a string. I believe you actually want to just do

```
data['rating'] = this.rating;
```

instead of

```
data['rating'] = json.encode(this.rating);
```

Answer (score 1):

here is the solution;

i used this;

```
data['rating'] = FieldValue.arrayUnion([this.rating]);
```

instead of

```
data['rating'] = json.encode(this.rating);
```

or

```
data['rating'] = this.rating; //both not working
```

for getting data; (I don't like this solution, but worked)

```
var asd = json["rating"] as List;
Map qwee = asd[0];
String rtkey = qwee.keys.toList()[0].toString();
double rtvalue = qwee.values.toList()[0];
rating = {rtkey: rtvalue} ;
```